# How to align all div content in one line?

Tags: css

I've this div:

```
<div id="footer" class="footer">
   <div class="footer-container">
     <p>Hello World</p> |
     <span id="select-language" class="label label-info">
         some text
     </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I align all tag inside `footer` in one line? I tried this:

```
.footer-container
{
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: `.footer-container { display: flex }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code the simplest way would be to use asterix as a selector to select all the elements inside the footer and give them the `display: inline-block` style like this (before the display attribute was given only to the footer-container):

```css
.footer-container {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.footer-container * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer" class="footer">
  <div class="footer-container">
    <p>Hello World</p>|
    <span id="select-language" class="label label-info">
         some text
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block` should be added on elements inside `.footer-container`.

```css
.footer-container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.footer-container p {
  margin: 0;
}
.footer-container p,
.footer-container span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer" class="footer">
   <div class="footer-container">
     <p>Hello World</p> |
     <span id="select-language" class="label label-info">
         some text
     </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:inline-block`:

```css
.footer-container
{
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.footer-container p,
.footer-container span{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer" class="footer">
   <div class="footer-container">
     <p>Hello World</p> |
     <span id="select-language" class="label label-info">
         some text
     </span>
    </div>
</div>
```